# Updating an object with builder pattern

Tags: java, builder

I recently found about this pattern and tried to implement it into my project. It does what it suppose to do. However, tried to find a nice solution to update it. Came up with one solution and I would like to know if it is "acceptable".

Only one difference which I did is I created another constructor inside Builder class which takes calling object as parameter:

```
public Builder (User user) {
    this.userID = user.getUserID();
    this.userName = user.getUserName();
    ...
    //and so on
```

and in main method

creating an object:

```
User user = new User.Builder("mandatory params")
                    .email("some email")
                    .build();
```

and update:

```
user = new User.Builder(user).phoneNumber("my number").build();
```

Is this approach acceptable?

Comment: You might find the [Immutables](https://immutables.github.io) library interesting. It takes all the work out of implementing builders for immutable objects. Some people like Lombok for the same reason. (I'm not affiliated with either project, just a happy user of Immutables).

Comment: do you really think you re saving typing and improving readability with builders? now the code is arbitrarily indented, and people will abuse long lines, thus line wrapping styles will mess everything in reformatters.. meanwhile you have to write both a builder and the get/set. Much maintenance.

Comment: Depends, but they can have benefits if several construction parameters can be blank and/or you validate multiple parameters together.

Answer (score 3):

This is good if you want to create a *new* user with fields copied from another user, with some changes:

```
anotherUser = new User.Builder(user).phoneNumber("my number").build();
```

But if you are assigning the new object back to the `user` variable, it suggests that you are *updating* the existing user. To update, you are creating a whole new object and copying fields, which is very inefficient. You should use setters.

Comment: If I understand correctly, it still better to have setters even if your object is made, lets say, of 10 parameters?

Comment: @EduardasŠlutas I think updating something at a memory location will almost always be more efficient than provisioning a new memory location. Creating a new object can be more efficient in a case, for example, where you need to set all elements (thousands) of an int array to 0.

Comment: Using setters 1. beats the purpose of encapsulation 2. beats the purpose of the buillder, which is supposed to validate that some complex configuration is preserved after the creation, or update in this case.

Answer (score -1):

you should you setter's and getter's once you have the object empty or partially filled doesn't matter.

Also In my opinion it's better to use [jackson](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial) `objectMapper` compare to builder pattern it automatically handles new parameters without adding extra line of code in the builder pattern and also it's more `clean code`.