# "Updater" design pattern, as opposed to "Builder"

Tags: python, oop, language-agnostic, builder, object-oriented-analysis

This is actually language agnostic, but I always prefer Python.

---

[The builder design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) is used to validate that a configuration is valid prior to creating an object, via delegation of the creation process.

Some code to clarify:

```
class A():
    def __init__(self, m1, m2):  # obviously more complex in life
        self._m1 = m1
        self._m2 = m2

class ABuilder():
    def __init__():
        self._m1 = None
        self._m2 = None

    def set_m1(self, m1):
        self._m1 = m1
        return self

    def set_m2(self, m1):
        self._m2 = m2
        return self

    def _validate(self):
        # complicated validations
        assert self._m1 < 1000
        assert self._m1 < self._m2

    def build(self):
        self._validate()
        return A(self._m1, self._m2)
```

---

My problem is similar, with an extra constraint that I can't re-create the object each time due to to performance limitations.
Instead, I want to only update an existing object.

---

### Bad solutions I came up with:

I could do [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54916703/updating-an-object-with-builder-pattern) and just use setters like so

```
class A():
    ...

    set_m1(self, m1):
        self._m1 = m1

    # and so on
```

But this is bad because using setters

1. Beats the purpose of encapsulation
2. Beats the purpose of the buillder (now updater), which is supposed to validate that some complex configuration is preserved after the creation, or update in this case.

---

As I mentioned earlier, I can't recreate the object every time, as this is expensive and I only want to update some fields, or sub-fields, and still validate or sub-validate.

---

I could add update and validation methods to `A` and call those, but this beats the purpose of delegating the responsibility of updates, and is intractable in the number of fields.

```
class A():
   ...

   def update1(m1):
      pass # complex_logic1

   def update2(m2):
      pass # complex_logic2

   def update12(m1, m2):
      pass # complex_logic12
```

---

I could just force to update every single field in `A` in a method with optional parameters

```
class A():
   ...

   def update("""list of all fields of A"""):
      pass
```

Which again is not tractable, as this method will soon become a god method due to the many combinations possible.

Forcing the method to always accept changes in `A`, and validating in the `Updater` also can't work, as the `Updater` will need to look at `A`'s internal state to make a descision, causing a circular dependency.

---

### How can I delegate updating fields in my object `A`

in a way that

1. Doesn't break encapsulation of `A`
2. Actually delegates the responsibility of updating to another object
3. Is tractable as `A` becomes more complicated

I feel like I am missing something trivial to extend building to updating.

Comment: If we're being very strict, then any way that a class delegates field-setting to another class ipso facto violates encapsulation. The way to guarantee your object doesn't get into an illegal state as a result of updates, is to not expose any methods which could leave it in an illegal state if called with the wrong arguments.

Comment: @kaya3 Is there a way to define setters that will only ever be used by the updater? I don't call this "breaking encapsulation". Just defining global setters does break it though. We could call the `updater` a friend of `A`.

Comment: Think about the "message passing" interpretation of OOP. If a method is only supposed to be called by a particular caller, then the "message" must be one that only that caller is able to send; but OOP defines an object's interface by what kinds of messages it accepts and how it should deal with them, not where it should accept those messages from. At best you could make the "caller" part of the message (i.e. have an argument to say which object is calling), and then the object checks that the caller is allowed, but there would be nothing stopping a caller from sending a different argument.

Comment: If you want your object to be updateable, then the update methods (i.e. setters) belong on the object itself, not a different class. If there are certain updates which should not be allowed because they result in an illegal state, then it is a setter method's responsibility to ensure that it only performs legal updates. Normally you would throw an exception if an illegal update is attempted (e.g. `IllegalArgumentException` in Java, or `ValueError` in Python).

Comment: @kaya3 What you wrote 2 comments up sounds like some kind of double dispatch or visitor could maybe help with, but I can't really put it together.

Comment: Perhaps in principle you could use double dispatch to achieve it, but it still violates encapsulation - if you have a class `A`, and a class `AUpdater` which is responsible for maintaining `A`'s invariant (i.e. making sure `A` instances stay in legal states) then your class `A` is written in a way which doesn't maintain its own invariant. That's a no-no, and it's what encapsulation is meant to prevent. See [this Q&A](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/355638/understanding-object-oriented-invariants) for a relevant discussion.

Comment: To be clear, the `Builder` pattern example at the start of your question also violates encapsulation in this way, because you're doing the validation only in the builder, not the constructor. This means your class `A` allows itself to be instantiated with an illegal state, because it made the other class `ABuilder` responsible for maintaining its invariant, instead of taking responsibility for its own invariant.

Comment: If `Builder` is a public inner class of `A`, and the constructor is private (not in Python), then theoretically, `A` is the one responsible for its own invariant. Is this statement wrong?

Comment: Interesting question; in that case I think you would view the class `A` and its inner class `ABuilder` together as a single module, and it would make sense to think of that module as being properly encapsulated if neither class can be used to put an instance of either class in an illegal state. The question would then be whether this coarser-grained encapsulation is better; the module is encapsulated from the outside world, but within the module the classes are not encapsulated from each other. Personally, I'd rather encapsulate at the class level by validating in `A`'s constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand all of your concerns, but I want to try and answer your post. From what you have written I assume:

- Validation is complex and multiple properties of an object must be checked to decide if any change to the object is valid.
- The object must always be in a valid state. Changes that make the object invalid are not permitted.
- It is too expensive to copy the object, make the change, validate the object, and then reject the change if the validation fails.

Move the validation logic out of the builder and into a separate class like ModelValidator with a `validateModel(model)` method

The first option is to use a **command pattern**.

- Create abstract class or interface named `Update` (I don't think Python abstract classes/interfaces, but that's fine). The `Update` interface implements two methods, `execute()` and `undo()`.
- A concrete class has a name like `UpdateAdress`, `UpdatePortfolio`, or `UpdatePaymentInfo`.
- Each concrete Update object also holds a reference to your *model object*.
- The concrete classes hold the state needed to for a particular kind of update. Imageine these methods exist on the `UpdateAddress` class:

```
UpdateAddress
    setStreetNumber(...)
    setCity(...)
    setPostcode(...)
    setCountry(...)
```

The update object needs to hold both the current and new values of a property. Like:

```
setStreetNumber(aString):
    self.oldStreetNumber = model.getStreetNumber
    self.newStreetNumber = aString
```

When the execute method is called, the model is updated:

```
execute:
    model.setStreetNumber(newStreetNumber)
    model.setCity(newCity)
    # Set postcode and country

    if not ModelValidator.isValid(model):
        self.undo()
        raise ValidationError
```

and the undo method looks like:

```
undo:
    model.setStreetNumber(oldStreetNumber)
    model.setCity(oldCity)
    # Set postcode and country
```

That is a lot of typing, but it would work. Mutating your model object is nicely encapsulated by different kinds of updates. You can execute or undo the changes by calling those methods on the update object. You can even store a list of update objects for multi-level undos and re-tries.

However, it is a lot of typing for the programmer. Consider using persistent data structures. Persistent data structures can be used to copy objects very quickly -- approximately constant time complexity. Here is a [python library of persistent data structures](https://github.com/tobgu/pyrsistent).

Let's assume your data was in a persistent data structure version of a dict. The library I referenced calls it a `PMap`.

The implementation of the update classes can be simpler. Starting with the constructor:

```
UpdateAddress(pmap)
    self.oldPmap = pmap
    self.newPmap = pmap
```

The setters are easier:

```
setStreetNumber(aString):
   self.newPmap = newPmap.set('streetNumber', aString)
```

Execute passes back a new instance of the model, with all the updates.

```
execute:
    if ModelValidator.isValid(newModel):
         return newModel;
    else:
         raise ValidationError
```

The original object has not changed at all, thanks to the magic of persistent data structures.

**The best thing is to not do any of this**. Instead, use an **[ORM](https://www.fullstackpython.com/object-relational-mappers-orms.html)** or **[object database](https://zodb.org/en/latest/tutorial.html)**. That is the "enterprise grade" solution. These libraries give you sophisticated tools like transactions and object version history.